# How to fight against Google Captchas appearing on searches from a school network?

Tags: google-search, recaptcha

When I do a Google Search from our school network, every time we have to solve a Captcha, because Google identifies it as [unusual traffic](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en). We analyzed the traffic for a while and there is definitely no bot or anything else which spams Google from our network.

All traffic originated from a single public IP, which I understand is the problem.

Is there a solution to get rid of the Captchas without splitting up the network into different groups and assigning different public IP addresses?

Comment: Related from Server Fault [Google is blocking our requests due to “automated queries”; what's the best way to find out why?](https://serverfault.com/q/151417/300641)

Comment: as mentioned we analyse our logs and there is no bot or similar

Comment: I suggest you to post your question on [sf] as this site is pointed to end-users rather than IT admins.

Comment: Sounds good. Can you move the question there?

Comment: AFAIK I can't because it's an old question.